django updateview define clean_attr on automatic form
I'm deriving from UpdateView, and I would like to use the automatic form,
but add a validation test for a field.
ModelForm offers clean_, which is just what I need.
My problem is overriding that method on a class that my code is not building
I can do this... but is there a cleaner way ?
def check_myattr(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data["myattr"]
    if anything_wrong(data) :
        raise ValidationError("not like that")
    return data
    
class SomeEditView(UpdateView):
    model         = Some
    fields        = ('myattr', 'more')
    template_name = "/some_edit.html"
    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        """Return an instance of the form to be used in this view."""
        if form_class is None:
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
        setattr(form_class, 'clean_myattr', check_myattr)
        return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())

